# http.Server {} - multiple handlers?

Tags: go

I have a structural problem: I can't figure out how I can do with the way I built it up now (I can find solutions where I can see it work with other models).

I'm using standard `net/http`, and I initiate my server with the following code:

```
gv := GlobalVars{
    jobs:             make(chan QueueElement),
    appConfig:        appConfig,
}

go worker(&gv)

server := http.Server{
    Handler: &gv,
    Addr:    ":" + appConfig.Port,
}

log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
```

Then I have one handler that checks for all the routes in a case:

```
func (gv *GlobalVars) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

}
```

The application is starting up some APIs that pass jobs to a queue.

My issue is, I need to start up 3 of these (different queues, different config) but same globalvar structure.

But this one only has one Handler that I can set - how would I add multiple handlers (I don't want multiple servers, has to run on the same port) that can understand its addressing different globalvars variables?

```
server := http.Server{
    Handler: &gv,
    Addr:    ":" + appConfig.Port,
}
```

Comment: Should all of the 3 queues receive the same requests, or do you want each one of them to handle different requests?

Comment: same structure and same worker code, but different worker for each of the 3 queues ( 1 each )

Comment: My question was about serving the incoming requests. When a request is sent to your server, what should happen? Should all three queues handle that request? Or should a single request be handled always by only one queue?

Comment: ah sorry, no there will be a set of api's that is associated to each queue, the worker associated for each queue will be executing a different external process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the [net.http.ServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) type:

> ServeMux is an HTTP request multiplexer. It matches the URL of each incoming request against a list of registered patterns and calls the handler for the pattern that most closely matches the URL.

A ServeMux is itself an `http.Handler` and multiplexes to different *subhandlers* by request route.
From what I understand of your question, you want to have different handlers on the same server, and each handler addresses a different queue with a different config.

Using a ServeMux one can achieve that easily:

```
gv1 := GlobalVars{
    jobs:             make(chan QueueElement),
    appConfig:        appConfig1,
}
gv2 := GlobalVars{
    jobs:             make(chan QueueElement),
    appConfig:        appConfig2,
}
gv3 := GlobalVars{
    jobs:             make(chan QueueElement),
    appConfig:        appConfig3,
}

sm := http.NewServeMux()
// Let gv{1,2,3} handle routes{1,2,3} respectively
sm.Handle("/route1", &gv1)
sm.Handle("/route2", &gv2)
sm.Handle("/route3", &gv3)

// Register the ServeMux as the sole Handler. It will delegate to the subhandlers.
server := http.Server{
    Handler: sm,
    Addr:    ":" + globalAppConfig.Port,
}
```

Note, you don't have to construct an `http.Server` by yourself. If you just need one server, you can use http package level functions [http.ListenAndServe](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) and [http.Handle](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle) which take care of creating a Server and default ServeMux for you.

```
// same GlobalVars as above
// ...

// Instead of creating a ServeMux we can use the global DefaultServeMux
http.Handle("/route1", &gv1)
http.Handle("/route2", &gv2)
http.Handle("/route3", &gv3)

// Calling the package level ListenAndServe uses the single global server.
// Passing nil as the Handler uses the DefaultServeMux as Handler on which we registered the Handlers above.
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":" + globalAppConfig.Port, nil)
```

**UPDATE**

A small example of the standard `ServeMux` with two `Handler`s serving 3 routes

```
// Keeping this type simple for the example
type GlobalVars struct {
    appConfig string
}

// This method makes every GlobalVars a net.http.Handler
func (gv *GlobalVars) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s here. Receiving request for %s\n", gv.appConfig, req.URL.Path)
}

func main() {
    gv1 := &GlobalVars{
        appConfig: "gv1",
    }
    gv2 := &GlobalVars{
        appConfig: "gv2",
    }

    // Handle requires a route and a Handler, our gvs are Handlers.
    // gv1 handles two routes, while gv2 handles only one.
    http.Handle("/route1", gv1)
    http.Handle("/route2", gv1)
    http.Handle("/route3", gv2)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

If I call all three routes after one another, I will receive the following responses:

```
$ curl localhost:8000/route1
gv1 here. Receiving request for /route1
$ curl localhost:8000/route2
gv1 here. Receiving request for /route2
$ curl localhost:8000/route3
gv2 here. Receiving request for /route3
```

This shows how to use stateful variables as Handlers (e.g. variables of type GlobalVars).

**NOTE**: The handler method `ServeHTTP` has a pointer receiver for `GlobalVars`. This means the method could potentially change the `GlobalVars` variable. HTTP Handlers are executed concurrently (imagine multiple requests to the same handler in a very short time period, you'll want to stay as responsive as possible). This example only reads the appConfig value, so it's fine. Once a write to the variable/field comes into the mix, however, you'll need proper synchronization.

Comment: looks cool ! will try it out - i am able to add more routes per gv right ?

Comment: Sure, just register the same gv Handler on multiple different routes. It will then serve all of those.

Comment: trying it out here, but one thing i am not sure of is how does it know what serveHTTP to go to ? or what requesthandler ex /route2 has compared to /route3 ?

Comment: Not sure I am following you, but do you mean how to ServeMux decides which implementation of Handler to call? It does it based on the incoming request URL path.

Comment: what i mean is if they all go through the same serveHTTP like im doing it today - so i just have swithcase like today for what route it is ex "case  'route1/':" - then serveHTTP will know just by the api route in text what GV its associated to ?

Comment: would you able to add a handler to your example for route1,route2,route3 ? am simply not able to get my head around this servemux, reading alot on it but all examples i come across are a single handler or examples where they pass on a function of the handler to it ( and in my case here im not passing a function but a variable structure )

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you're asking, but I added a small example nonetheless ;)

Comment: thanks alot - it was exactly this one i wasnt sure of :) marking it as the answer and thankyou so much.